# Linux free / kill TCP port - Closed

Tags: linux

I have tcp port listening at 3299, When I use

```
netstat -tulpn | grep :3299
```

It shows

```
tcp   0    0 0.0.0.0:3299        0.0.0.0:*                   LISTEN      -
```

I tried

```
fuser -k 3299/tcp
```

but it says

```
-bash: fuser: command not found
```

Comment: Did you run the netstat command as root ? You might need the full path to `fuser` if you're not root though. `/usr/sbin/fuser`

Comment: thanks, I was not running it as root, when logged in using root, i see the process id and I killed it using kill -9 <pid>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was not running below command as root user, so it was not showing me process id of this process.

```
tcp   0    0 0.0.0.0:3299        0.0.0.0:*                   LISTEN      -
```

Once I logged in using root user, i see its process id,

```
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:3299 0.0.0.0:*             LISTEN      8047/java
```

then i killed it using 
    kill -f 8047

Answer (score 0):

You can do it automatically using the following script:

```
for i in `lsof -i TCP:8047  | awk '{ print $2 }'`; do kill -9 $i; done
```